# Concern with "modify all data" permission to upload a new version of a file

Tags: permissions, fileupload

As per the documentation regarding [Upload a New Version of a File](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_versioning.htm&type=5), the note section says that

> Only file owners, collaborators, and users with the Modify All Data
> permission can upload new versions of a file.

When we enable **Modify All Data**, this doc points out to all the permissions that will be enabled as soon as **Modify All Data** is enabled - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384401&type=1

Is there an alternative (possibly a lower level permission) targeted just for the functionality, that takes care of uploading a new version of a file in Salesforce ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to upload a new version of a file in Salesforce without having the **Modify All Data** permission.

- If the file is a **Salesforce CRM Content** document, you can upload a new version if you are a member of the library where the document is stored, and you have one of these library privileges enabled: **“Add Content”**, **“Add Content On Behalf of Others”**, or **“Manage Library”**. You can check and edit your library permissions by going to the Library Management page.
- If the file is a **Chatter** file, you can upload a new version if you
  are the owner of the file or a collaborator on the file. You can add
  collaborators to a file by clicking Share on the file detail page and
  selecting the users or groups that you want to share the file with.
  You can also change the owner of a file by clicking Change Owner on
  the file detail page and selecting a new owner.
- If the file is an **attachment** to a record, you can upload a new version if you have the **Edit** permission on the record and the **Create** permission on the attachment. You can check and edit your object and field permissions by going to the **Profile** or **Permission Set** page.

Comment: you should add a link to the doc(s) where you got this from

Comment: The upload needs to happen via an API by a third party integration where grant would be done by a user belonging to the instance. 

In case of chatter file, it is not feasible to add the grant user as a collaborator for every file upload that would happen. Changing the owner also doesn't really help.

Also it would be helpful if you can link the Salesforce docs here more complete clarity and approach.

Comment: - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_settings_perms.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_versioning.htm&type=5
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8xzpSAB
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_revise.htm&type=5